# How can I avoid using exceptions in C++?

Tags: c++, exception

What techniques can I use to avoid exceptions in C++, as mentioned in [Google's style guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml?showone=Exceptions#Exceptions)?

Comment: Could you clarify your question?  As it stands, the answer would seem to be: you simply don't throw exceptions, and try to avoid the circumstances that cause external code to throw exceptions by defensive coding.

Comment: yes your understanding is correct.What is defensive coding?

Comment: Note that, even given what sharptooth said (http://stackoverflow.com/users/57428/sharptooth) -- and with all due respect to the smart people at Google --, I consider this a stupid style guide. Since it's nigh impossible to avoid exceptions altogether in C++, you will probably have to write exception-safe code anyway. Doing this without using exceptions means that you have to deal with all the disadvantages of exceptions but forgo their advantages. Now what's that good for?

Comment: @sbi: The design guide is kind of stupid in some other cases: It says that you should not use dynamic_cast<> because if you need it outside of unittests you probably have a design flaw. WHAT? I could understand arguments referring to performance or code size issues but calling all designs using dynamic_cast<> bad is weird! (Tell that to the C# people and their 'as' operator!)

Comment: Thanks for making me discover the Google Style Guide.

Comment: This is just silly <quote>For instance, if f() calls g() calls h(), and h throws an exception that f catches, g has to be careful or it may not clean up properly.</quote> g() will always clean up correctly that's guaranteed by the standard. If they mean pointers may leak then that's easily resolved by using smart pointers. There should be no RAW pointers in Exception safe code anyway.

Comment: @Martin: That implies using RAII and similar techniques which is in Google's eyes "Lots of supporting machinery"...

Comment: sbi: the point of the guideline is so that Google doesn't have to make all their existing C++ code exception-safe. Martin: it’s not just a matter of memory leaks; there are locks and there are the data-structure invariants that we protect with locks in multithreaded code. The standard doesn’t guarantee you’ll get this right. It just gives you the tools to do so.

Comment: rstevens: generic containers are the usual use for `dynamic_cast`, but they're kind of awkward in C++ due to the lack of a root type. Also, you can get them by using templates instead, and then you get compile-time type-safety. Are there other legitimate reasons to use `dynamic_cast` that I’m not seeing?

Comment: @Kragen: There are designs where a factory creates objects of a common base class on runtime (driven by a configuration file or similar) where compile-time-type-safety can't help. If you then need to downcast-with-test your class you could use dynamic_cast or something similar. 'similar' means you have to write something that provides the same functionality. This is legal when arguing against dynamic_cast's performance or code size impact but is such a design bad only by those arguments?

Comment: @Kragen: The company started as a research project in 1996. In 1998, when the C++ standard was released, most of the exceptions-safety battles were already fought. Why do they have so much exception-unsafe code that they need a guideline protecting it rather than fixing it? And given the fact that say themselves that they cannot prevent exceptions on Windows, isn't that just lowering probabilities of fatal errors? I'm sorry to say, but I find this ever more stupid the more I think about it.

Comment: @rstevens: I see the benefit of `dynamic_cast` when you have to ferry a derived class through some framework which only knows about the base class (with `dynamic_cast<MyWindow*>(theWindow)` being the classical example). Other than that, I don't think I needed it more than two or three times in the last decade.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Don't throw exceptions.
2. Don't use STL (which relies heavily on exceptions).
3. Use only `new(std::nothrow)` or override `::operator new` to return 0 on failure.

Note that by avoiding exceptions, you're effectively throwing out lots of useful libraries, including Boost. Basically, you'll have to program everything from scratch.

Comment: I didn't realize the STL "relied heavily on exceptions", and indeed I remember that STL being incompatible with exceptions used to be a big problem. But I guess it does at least insofar as it has no other way to deal with allocation failures.

Comment: It not just a question of allocation failures. Exceptions are the only way to indicate failure from constructors, notably from copy-constructors that are called on items during inserts.

Comment: Check out the EASTL, an STL without exceptions.

Comment: @Edouard: Is the EASTL written by Google? :-)

Comment: I don't think you're allowed to override `operator new` to fail in that way. You certainly shouldn't. It would force correct code to check for NULL pointers even when they're intentionally using the throwing `new`.

Comment: avakar: When would it be a good idea to store an object in an STL container whose copy-constructor could fail for some reason other than a memory allocation failure?  It seems like the common cases (acquiring some other resource like a file descriptor or lock, or invalid constructor arguments) are excluded from this condition. You sure don’t want the STL copying your RAII lock objects behind your back!

Comment: The EASTL sure is interesting.  Too bad it's not possible to get it.

Comment: Kragen, STL containers are allowed to copy the contained objects as they see fit. The copy-construction can, however, fail at any time. Operations on containers generally have strong exception guarantees: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_guarantees.

Comment: @Edouard And how exactly is he supposed to check out a closed source library that is not even licensed?

Answer (score 4):

Not throwing exceptions in your own code is relatively easy: you just don't use the `throw` statement.

Not throwing exceptions from memory allocation failures is a little more painful: either you don't use normal `new` (use `new(std::nothrow)` or `malloc` or something instead), or you use some nonstandard compiler option to get it to do something nonstandard when it fails (e.g. immediately terminate your program, or return `0`), or you override `operator new` to do something nonstandard when it fails.

If your chosen approach is to immediately terminate the program, you can implement this with `set_new_handler()`, which I had forgotten about until litb reminded me.

That leaves the problem of dealing with exceptions generated by C++ libraries you don't maintain.  Generally you'll have to wrap library calls in a wrapper that looks something like this:

```
int DoSomething(int &output, const int input) throw() {
  try {
    output = library_do_something(input);
    return 1;
  } catch (...) {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

The `catch (...)` catches all possible C++ exceptions from `library_do_something` (as well as the assignment operator on `output`, which isn't relevant here), throws away all the information they may have contained, and then maps all those failures to `0`.

Note that this style means that you can't use RAII at all, not even a little bit, because you have no way of signaling failure within a constructor. The whole point of RAII is that you acquire all your resources inside of constructors so that they will be properly released by a destructor during exception propagation. But resource acquisition is something that can essentially always fail. So you can't do that inside a constructor.

Comment: You can install a new handler. Operator new will call it when it doesn't have memory available, and from that handler, you can either manage to get memory or terminate the program.

Comment: I had forgotten about `set_new_handler()`, thanks, litb! I'm updating my answer.

Comment: Just do `kill(0,9)` instead of throwing an exception. OK, you'll also be kissing your whole process group goodbye, but that pesky exception won't be disturbing your beautiful code! ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I'm interested to know why one would want to avoid exceptions in C++ and what mechanism one would replace them with to deal with the reality of unexpected failure while still maintaining decent structure.

Sure adding them to a existing codebase that doesn't use RAII type semantics is extremely costly - but if one is doing green field development then what alternative would you suggest and how are going to justify not using high quality libraries that do use exceptions vs. writing your own exception free / bug free alternatives?

Comment: In addition to the performance and space problems of exceptions, which empirically exist even though people deny them, some platforms simply don't support exceptions in a trustworthy way. Some embedded machines' C++ compilers, for example, just don't have working exceptions.

Comment: Personally I don't like using exceptions in C++, because it makes it extremely difficult to predict the control flow of the program.  Since any C++ function can throw any exception without declaring it, using exceptions means that you can't predict what *any* function will do unless you grovel over the *entire* call tree beneath it.  That means that verifying the behavior of a function wrt exceptions is a problem with geometrically expanding cost for the programmer. Java, OTOH, gets it right--Java methods declare the exceptions they can throw, and the declarations are enforced at compile time.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: That's why we always code to the exception safety guarantees - so that it doesn't matter what the execution path is.

Answer (score 1):

The style guide says they "don't use exceptions" which is just that - they don't throw them and don't call anything that could throw them (for example, they would use the `new(std::nothrow)` instead of usual `new` because the latter will throw `bad_alloc` when it fails to allocate memory.

Comment: Or they don't use these library

Comment: They can wrap them and have and have a catch(...) around all the contents in every wrapper function.

Answer (score 0):

In some compilers, you may be able to turn off exception handling.  This could cause unexpected results with external code though - it is not something I would want to try.

Other than that, the obvious first step would be to avoid throwing exceptions from your own code, probably with liberal use of the [nothrow directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/49147z04%28VS.80%29.aspx), and attempt to avoid throwing exceptions from external (3rd party) code through [defensive programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming).

That means that your code needs to be aware of possible external exceptional failure conditions all the time, such as running out of memory, out of disk space, loss of an internet connection, hardware failure, and any number of other circumstances that might cause code to throw...

In some cases you may be able to use exception-free versions of some code (such as throwing-new vs. non-throwing new).

Answer (score 0):

What I do is to never throw exceptions with my own code, and to "translate" or wrap any external code that does that.